# How to create a php page with login using cookies?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cookies, authentication

I want to create an admin page with login and if the user is logged and he is admin in my database the content must appear, if is not an admin the content will appear but without some privileges. And if the user and password did not match with any user and password form database a message error must appear.

This is my HTML code:

```
<form action="admin.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr><td>
        <label>User:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label> </td> <td><input type="text" class="text" name="user"/> <span></span>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <label>Password:</label> </td> <td> <input type="password" class="text" name="pass"/> <span></span>
    </td></tr>
    <tr ><td colspan="2">
    <p align=center><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Log In" /> </p>
    </td></tr>
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
        $user = $_POST['user'] ;
        $pass = $_POST['pass'] ;
        $sql='SELECT * FROM users';
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

My table is:

```
 |ID_user| user |password|is_admin|
 |   1   |admin | admin  |    1   |
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it! The answer:

admin.php

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="main_r">';
    require_once('config.php');
    if (isset($_GET['err'])){
         $err=$_GET['err'];
    if($err==1)
         echo'<h4>Pls insert user and pass!</h4>';
    else if ($err==2)
         echo'<h4>User and pass are incorect!</h4>';
    }
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["TestCookie"]))  
         echo'
         <form action="dologin.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr><td>
            <label>User:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label> </td> <td><input type="text" class="text" name="user"/> <span></span>
            </td></tr>
            tr><td>
            <label>Pass:</label> </td> <td> <input type="password" class="text" name="pass"/> <span></span>
            </td></tr>
            <tr ><td colspan="2">
            <p align=center><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Log In" /> </p>
            </td></tr>
        </table>';
        else{
            $curr = $_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
            $sql = "SELECT user, admin FROM useri WHERE ID_user='$curr'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            echo'<h4>Welcome '.$row['user'].'</h4>
            </div>';
        }
```

dologin.php

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass']))
{
$user = $_POST['user'] ;
$pass = $_POST['pass'] ;
$pass_hash = md5($pass);
$err = 0;

if (!empty($user) && !empty($pass))
{
    $sql="SELECT ID_user FROM useri WHERE user='$user' AND password='$pass_hash'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if ($result)
    {
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);                
        if($num_rows==0) 
            $err=2;
        else if ($num_rows==1) 
        {
            $ID_user = $row['ID_user'];
            //echo $ID_user;
            setcookie("TestCookie",$ID_user, time()+3600);
        }
    } 
} else
    $err=1;
header("Location: http://yoursite/admin.php?err=".$err);
exit;       
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL is already.. not good. You're using mysql_, but let's skip that for now. You're not checking if the user exists and if the passwords match.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = $user AND `password` = $pass");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { //so if user exists where user = adimouse91 and pass = mouse, it'll be one
 echo 'this is content for logged in users';
}

$isAdmin = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($isAdmin['is_admin'] == '1') {
 echo 'this is content for admins';
}
```

I have not taken into account password salts and hashing in general (which you should do!) or sessions. Sessions make your life easier (imagine if you could just do `if($_SESSION['admin'] == 1) { }`!).